# Dynamic Popover in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and I'm using the Ant Design framework (https://ant.design/).

I have a table list of items that I'm looking to have a button on each so that when it is pressed additional information about that row becomes available (which is a secondary API call specific to that row).

I'm trying to use a popover but I'm noticing that the popover wants the text before being rendered which is a problem since I don't have that information until the second API call. The best idea I've come up so far is to have the button press trigger the api call and then the state is updated but that creates a funky experience (as it is update after the popover is already opened - after starting with the previous rows information). It isn't a huge amount of time but it still isn't an ideal experience.

This is what I have so far:

```
<Popover content={this.contentSec([record['section']])} title= 
   {record['section']} trigger="click">
   <Button onClick={() => this.sectionAttributes(record['section'])}>
      <Icon type="info-circle-o" />
   </Button>
</Popover>
```

this.sectionAttributes triggers my fetch request. and this.contentSec does the formatting on the existing popup (see below).

```
contentSec(props) {
    const listItems = this.state.attributes.map((item) =>
       <li>{item}</li>
    );

    return <div><ul>{listItems}</ul></div>
}
```

Any ideas of a better way to handle this so that there isn't that buggy delay when clicking the button for the popover?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the content is populated *after* the second api call, You can send two props `content` which can be empty string or any default value and `loading` variable as `true` on click. Once you have the data after the API call you can send the updated props ie `content` with actual text and `loading` as false and finally handle your logic and state update in `componentwillrecieveprops()` in the popover component.

You can use the `loading` prop to switch from a loader initially to the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Write a condition to check if the response from  this.sectionAttributes(record['section'] is true, if it is true then

```
<Popover content={this.contentSec([record['section']])} title= 
   {record['section']} trigger="click">
   <Button onClick={() => this.sectionAttributes(record['section'])}>
      <Icon type="info-circle-o" />
   </Button>
</Popover>
```

else simply use

```
<Button onClick={() => this.sectionAttributes(record['section'])}>
      <Icon type="info-circle-o" />
</Button>
```

For the first time user clicks on button, the component rerenders and state gets updated, so when it rerenders you can see popover as the if condition satisfy.